# Building MongoDB query with conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to build a MongoDB query by pushing a new language if it does not exist in the array already. But if it exists I get an error this '$push' is empty. It is correct.

My question is how to build the query adding $push only when it is necessary?

```
let pushNewLanguage = {};
if (!profile.languages || (profile.languages && !profile.languages.find(l => l === languageId))) {
    pushNewLanguage = { languages: languageId };
}

const profileUpdate = await 
Profiles.rawCollection().update(
    { userId: this.userId }, 
    { 
        $inc: { countPublishedPoems: 1 },
        $push: pushNewLanguage 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing Javascript, you can create a "base" update object, and then add the `$push` property if you need:

```
const update = { 
    $inc: { countPublishedPoems: 1 }
}

if (!profile.languages || (profile.languages && !profile.languages.find(l => l === languageId))) {
    update["$push"] = { languages: languageId };
}

const profileUpdate = await 
Profiles.rawCollection().update(
    { userId: this.userId }, 
    update
);
```

Comment: Nice! I was looking for this solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the conditional logic and use `$addtoSet` instead of `$push`.

[$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) will only add the item if it doesn’t exist already.

```
const profileUpdate = await 
Profiles.rawCollection().update(
    { userId: this.userId }, 
    { 
        $inc: { countPublishedPoems: 1 },
        $addToSet: { languages: languageId } 
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I can use it also, but Ozw gave me more correct answer for my question. :)